# WebService management

Tags: deployment, jenkins

I have a few web-services which all are parts of one application. They all built with [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) and builds stored in folders. To run them all I starting few ssh sessions, doing a lot of scp's, and run each with `nohup ./start -Dport=.. &`

It was ok until is was the only application. But now there are five. And each deploy is like a hell.

So, is there any software to automate this? I want it could copy few files over ssh, run few bash scripts, monitor service activity and expose it over web-ui. It is possible to create something by myself, but I don't want to reinvent a bicycle.

Answer (score 1):

[Kwatee](http://kwatee.net) (I'm the developer) is a free tool that does just that. You have a web ui to configure and operate the deployment on any number of servers. You can also automate the whole process in a continuous build environment via ant/maven plugins or python shell commands.